# jsPlumb: How to make conditional connections

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, jsplumb

Am trying to create connections between nodes based on rules for example:
[image]

1. "API request" endpoint can't connect to any other nodes except the "Initiate Call".
2. "Failed" endpoint can't connect to "Play Audio"
   And so on...

and here is my endpoints definition code:

```
let addEndpoints = function(toId, sourceAnchors, targetAnchors) {
    console.log(toId, sourceAnchors, targetAnchors);
    for (var i = 0; i < sourceAnchors.length; i++) {
      var sourceUUID = toId + sourceAnchors[i];
      instance.addEndpoint(toId, sourceEndpoint, {
        anchor: sourceAnchors[i],
        uuid: sourceUUID
      });
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < targetAnchors.length; j++) {
      var targetUUID = toId + targetAnchors[j];
      instance.addEndpoint(toId, targetEndpoint, {
        anchor: targetAnchors[j],
        // anchor: 'Continuous',
        uuid: targetUUID
      });
    }
  };
```

anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searches i figured out how to access endpoints uuids, but as the
above answer it must be called in `beforeDrop` interceptor like this:

```
    instance.bind("beforeDrop", function(info) {
      ...
    });
```

This event is fired when a new or existing connection has been dropped, so now `info` contains what we need to access, to get source endpoint the command will be like this:
`info.connection.endpoints[0].getUuid()`
and to get target endpoint:
`info.dropEndpoint.getUuid()`.

Now the full condition will be something like this:

```
 if (info.connection.endpoints[0].getUuid().includes("start") &&
  info.dropEndpoint.getUuid().includes("playaudio")) {
 instance.deleteConnection(connInfo.connection)
  } else {
   init(info.connection);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `beforeDrop` interceptor for this:

https://docs.jsplumbtoolkit.com/community-2.x/current/articles/events-community.html#evt-beforedrop

You can see it in use (not exactly how you want to use it, it pops up a confirmation in this demo) here:

https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/demonstration/draggableConnectors

Try dragging one of the blue endpoints to one of the other blue endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for your response, How to implement same idea in my case, as u see endpoints created based on for loop with incremented value

Comment: The way the endpoints are created shouldn't have an enormous bearing on how you write the beforeDrop interceptor. The parameters to the interceptor include the connection being dragged and the endpoint on which it is being dropped.